# build a rating system: database structure involve user_id?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

**Description:**

I am building a rating system with `mysql/php`. I am confused as to how I would set up the database.

Here is my article setup:

**Article table:**

```
id | user_id | title | body | date_posted
```

This is my assumed rating table:

**Rating table:**

```
id | article_id | score | ? user_id ?
```

**Problem:**

I don't know if I should place the `user_id` in the rating table. My plan is to use a query like this:

```
 SELECT ... WHERE user_id = 1 AND article_id = 10
```

But I know that it's redundant data as it stores the `user_id` twice. Should I figure out a `JOIN` on the tables or is the structure good as is?

Comment: If you're not reusing `article_id`, then isn't `article_id = 10` sufficient to get a unique result? Or is `user_id` the user making the rating -- in which case it's not redundant?

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything wrong with this approach. The user id being stored twice is not particularly relevant since one is regarding a rating entry and the other, i assume, is related to the article owner.

The benefit of this way is you can prevent multiple scores being recorded for each user by making article_id and user_id unique and use replace into to manage scoring.

There are many things to elaborate on this depending on whether or not this rating system needs to be intelligent to prevent gaming, etc. How large the user base is, etc.

I bet for any normal person, this setup would not be detrimental to even a relatively large scale system.

... semi irrelevant:

Just FYI, depending on the importance and gaming aspects of this score, you could use STDDEV() to fetch an average factoring the standard deviation on the score column...

```
SELECT STDDEV(`score`) FROM `rating` WHERE `article_id` = {article_id}
```

That would factor outliers supposing you cared whether or not it looked like people were ganging up on a particular article to shoot it down or praise it without valid cause.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will be using `STDDEV`.

Answer (score 2):

It depends.  I'm assuming that the articles are unique to individual users?  In that case, I could retain the user_id in your rating table and then just alter your query to:

```
SELECT ... WHERE article_id = 10
```

or

```
SELECT ... WHERE user_id = 1
```

Depending on what info you're trying to pull.

You're not "storing the user_id twice" so much as using the user_id to link the article to unique data associated to the user in another table.  You're taking the right approach, except in your query.

Comment: My goal is to pull the average of article ratings along with the user who posted it. Article_id can have 100s of the same value and I will be pulling the average down. I guess I can pull that with just `article = 0`, thank you.

Comment: @Phil Actually... to clarify, is the user_id for the rating the user_id of the article author or the user_id of the user that rated it?  I'm assuming the latter... if not, my answer may not be correct.

Comment: I was meaning the former usage, but you pointed me in the right direction. haha. I am not putting `user_id` in the rating table, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You should though. Otherwise how will you prevent a user from rating an article 10,000 times?

Comment: can't I select the `user_id` by using the `article_id`? An article has only a unique user.

Comment: Like @KaiQing was getting at, if it were me, I would have a user_id field in my "rating" table but instead of it being associated with the article author, it would be associated with the person that left the rating.  This, like Kai mentioned, helps prevent unchecked ratings that could get out of control with no regulation.  In the case of the former route, you should use a `JOIN` to pull the `user_id` of the author from the `article_id`

Answer (score 0):

you should not, due to 3rd normal form, you need to keep the independence.

"The third normal form (3NF) is a normal form used in database normalization. 3NF was originally defined by E.F. Codd in 1971.[1] Codd's definition states that a table is in 3NF if and only if both of the following conditions hold:

- The relation R (table) is in second normal form (2NF)
- Every non-prime attribute of R is non-transitively dependent (i.e. directly dependent) on every superkey of R."

Source here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form

First normal Form: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form

Second normal Form: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form

you should take a look to normalization and E/R model it will help you a lot.

normalization in wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: okay, I know this wouldn't be normalized, haha. I guess I don't know how I could retrieve that data without the `user_id` in the rating table.